# same input different test case different answers

Tags: dynamic, c++14

The program is to find out whether the number of elements in an array which are not equal to 1 are less than given integer 'k'(input to program). 
The program takes an input 't' i.e. number of test cases, 'n' as number of elements in the array, 'k' as defined in problem statement.

t->test case

My Program :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int n,k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        int a[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n && k>=0;i++){

            cin >> a[i];
            if(a[i]!=1)
                k--;
        }
        if(k>=0)
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
            cout << "NO" << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

MY input: 
6 
2 2 
1 2 
5 6 
1 2 2 2 2 
5 3 
2 2 10 1 1 
5 3 
3 5 6 4 1 
5 3 
3 5 6 4 1 
5 3 
3 5 4 4 1

OUTPUT: 
YES 
 
YES 
YES 
NO 
YES 
YES

Problem: In 4th and 5th test case OUTPUT IS DIFFERENT.

The problem I can understand is that only in 5th test case the loop is only running for i=0 for the given 5th case then it breaks.

Comment: [Edit] the question and clarify what you mean by "test case". There is no test code here, so you need to be clear what you are trying and what you expect.

Comment: You don't generally read all `n` elements for each test. You may mistake the left-over element from previous test for the beginning of the next test. In particular, after a test that results in `NO` answer, future reading is off.

Comment: thanks @IgorTandetnik

Comment: edited the question @jdv
thanks for telling me

Answer (score 0):

In the loop where you are taking your input you have taken the condition 'i < n && k >= 0' i.e. if k becomes less than 0 (in the case when more than 'k' numbers are not equal to 1) then it breaks out of the loop but then you give the complete array(for the same test case) as input but your program is not taking the input for the same test case it has moved on. Do not take k>=0 as the breaking condition for the loop.

Corrected Code :

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int n,k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        int a[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){      // change in this line

            cin >> a[i];
            if(a[i]!=1)
                k--;
        }
        if(k>=0)
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
            cout << "NO" << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help !!

Comment: @user9440672 If the answer helped I would ask you to upvote the same and mark it as the helpful answer by clicking on check sign beside it.

Comment: dont have enough reputation